# r.series command in QGIS - timeseries

Tags: raster, grass-gis, order

I am using r.series command in qgis. The command is performing correctly, but when I import input raster files, it creates a list in a random order. Sometimes the order of input rasters is essential to the outcome. Is there a way to control the list of input rasters?

[the order of raster is random](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPRyV.png)

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use vrt (virtual raster format). The initial command line is gdalbuildvrt, which is also available directly in QGIS using

> Raster-> Miscellaneous-> Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)